# How to use diff3 in a shell script hp-ux

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to automate a process,

1. I have 3 files that must be synchronized,
2. Sometimes I have to modify manually one of them "the master file"
3. When I do that I need to copy the other 2 files using the `cp -p` command

I have this script that actually works, but I want to identify when "the master file" changes, because if I run this script always will change the other 2 files doesn't matter if they are the same.

I know that it happens because the exit_status will be always 0, so any advance will be grateful

```
#result=$(diff3 "the master file" file2 file3)
exit_status=$?
echo $exit_status
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "files are the same"
else
    echo "files are different"
    cp -p "the master file" file2
    cp -p "the master file" file3
    echo "$result"
fi
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? ksh eh?

Answer (score 0):

Use `stat` instead of `diff3` to check `masterfile` modification

```
while true
do
   if [ "$var" -ne "$(stat -c %Y masterfile)" ]
   then
     var=$(stat -c %Y masterfile) #Important step, updating var
     cp -p masterfile file2
     cp -p file2 file3
   else
     sleep 10m # I wish to check masterfile in another 10 minutes
   fi
done
```

**Note:** Tested on ksh version 93u+

Comment: Thank you will check and let you know :)

Comment: which shell are you using?